# Does the guild vault have collectible storage?

Tags: guild-wars-2

In Guild Wars 2  each character has a bank that they can store items in. One of the nice features is that it has a section for storing "collectibles" such as crafting materials. Guilds can also unlock a storage vault. Does this vault allow for storing collectibles in a similar manner?

Comment: I don't remember seeing this in the beta, maybe it will be implemented?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the official wiki for Shared Storage vs Account Storage there is no mention that Shared Storage has a collectables area. It was not present during the beta so unless it get added for launch the answer is no. However, you can put a collectable into shared storage. It just doesn't have a separate tab for it and counts as a space used in your overall storage where is is a separate item in your account vault.

- Shared Storage: http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Guild_Vault#Shared_storage
- Account Storage: http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Account_vault

Just confirming post-beta that Guild Storage does not have a separate area for Collectables:

[image]